# Using BouncyCastle JCE provider with jdk6

Tags: java, bouncycastle, apache-httpclient-4.x, java-6, apache-httpcomponents

I need to create a TSLv1.2 PSK connection using jdk6u12 with BouncyCastle and make some HTTP request with apache HTTPClient.
I tried to register the provider with `Security.addProvider()` and passing 
`SSLContext.getInstance("TSLv1.2")` to the `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`; but its still throw the `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.

Is it possible to achieve an `SSLContext` in such way or do i have to extend `SSLSocketFactory` in order to return a custom `SSLSocket`?

Comment: Can you add some code and the exception to the question?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me.

```
 Provider provider = new BouncyCastleJsseProvider();
 Security.addProvider(provider);
 SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2",provider.getName());
```